# How can I access a JsonResult variable in my code behind file from the javascript of my view? Razor Pages. C#

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, razor-pages

**Context**: I am trying to pass a nested JSON object from my code behind page to a method in the .js in my view.

**UI Flow**: The user selects an organization from a ddl, then the ddl's onchange function is called, onchange function clicks the hidden submit button, code behind method is called which creates the nested json object with the needed organizational data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Lessons Learned**:  I wasted too much time trying to make this happen via ajax.  It is possible (maybe preferred) to use ajax to achieve my goal.  If my page handler had been a get method, ajax would have been a quick solution.  However, ajax in razor pages required a hidden field to contain the anti-forgery token for ajax posts.  So why not use the razor page form to accomplish the same thing? This allows me to keep consistency throughout my application.

**Notes**: Please comment if there is a better way to do this.  I used the form with the hidden submit button because it is what I could do quickly.

**Solution**:

1. Put ddl in a form.

```
<form asp-page-handler="DdlValueSelected">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Select Me</label>
        <select class="form-control" onchange="ddlChanged()" asp-for="@Model.blah" asp- 
        items="@Model.blah"> 
        </select>        
    </div>
    <button hidden type="submit" id="ddlSubmitButton"></button>
</form>
```

2. Have the onchange method in your .js click the hidden submit button in the form.

```
function ddlChanged() {
    $('#ddlSubmitButton').click();
}
```

3a. In your code behind method, make service call to return the object you need.
3b. Convert object to object type of JsonResult.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostDdlValueSelected(string ddlValue) 
{
   DataNeededAsJsonObject = await _service.GetDataNeededAsJsonObject(ddlValue);
   ConvertedDataNeededAsJsonObject = new JsonResult(DataNeededAsJsonObject);
   return Page();
}
```

4. Access your code behind variable of type JsonResult by using @Json.Serialize(object) in your .js in your view.

```
function getJsonData() {
    jsonData = @Json.Serialize(Model.ConvertedDataNeededAsJsonObject);
    console.log(jsonData);
}
```

I welcome feedback, so I can do it better next time.